# Flexslider - using control container and directional arrow navigation?

Tags: flexslider

I'm using Flexslider, and right now am using the external control container feature - So I can control the slider via links in a different DIV container. However, I still want the rollover directional arrows when I rollover the slides. I have been unable to get both to work together. Any ideas?

```
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlsContainer: ".homeMidTopSection",
        controlNav: true,
        directionNav: true,
        manualControls: ".blockContent a",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem today and found this pastie (by the Flexslider author apparently): http://pastie.org/2582577

You need to change your controlsContainer: ".homeMidTopSection" to the slides container (in the documentation normally is .flexslider)

I am not sure if you can get the 'dots' type of pagination being shown as well (which might be useful for usability if your custom controls container is far away from the slideshow, and especially if it doesn't show the position in the slide show using the .flex-active class).

Answer (score 1):

today i used this feature, after a long time of searching...

```
$('#first').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshow:false,
    controlsContainer:".holder_arrow",
    start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
});
```

just create a div with above class name and some css customization and thats it. I hope it helps.....